# What exactly is a stationary point?

Tags: calculus

I am asked to find the stationary points of the function $y=5+24x-9x^2-2x^3$. When I looked on the wikipedia page for the definition of stationary points, I read that a stationary point is a point where the derivative equals zero.

However, when I looked at the same article in a different languages, points of inflection were included too, and as far as I know points of inflection are points where the **second** derivative equals zero. So which one is correct?

Comment: For stuff written in English at least, the first.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yeah, that was my guess too, however, this particular question got a lot of points in a past paper of an otherwise pretty difficult test, so I wondered whether or not perhaps they also wanted points of inflection. However, they then probably give points for having to realize how to find out which point is the minimum and which is the maximum (second derivative test)

Comment: It is probably connected to the second derivative test. A stationary point, for nice functions, may give as local max, a local min, or a point of inflection. But a point of inflection need not be a stationary point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y=x^3$ has a stationary point at $x=0$, even though this is *also* a point of inflection.

$y=x^3-x$ has two stationary points. It also has a point of inflection, bu that is not one of the stationary points.